# Simulating "Custom Quotes" with PHP

Tags: php, css, html

I don't know what it's called, so I'm just going to use the term custom quotes, what I mean by this is something like StackOverflow's styling, you use asterisks to make things bold, `**Like &nbsp;this**` and it will end up **Like this**, which probably does something
`<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Like this</span>`...  I looked up PHP's [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) but I was unsure if that was the right thing too look up.

---

To put it simple:

How do I get:

`-Text-`

to turn into:

`<span style='color: red;'>Text</span>`

Comment: Yes, that's the usual implementation. Google for a Wiki parser or Markdown for PHP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$message = 'Testing this **quote**';
$search = '/\*\*(.*?)\\*\*/';
$replace = '<span style="font-weight: bold;">\\1</span>';
echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/). Once you have it installed, you can do something like:

```
$my_text = "-Text-";
use \Michelf\Markdown;
$my_html = Markdown::defaultTransform($my_text);
```